# Access violation when i try free TJSONObject

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, datasnap

I have the code below, but when I try to free the variable checkID, I get an access violation error, and if I don't destroy it I will have a memory leak problem.

```
function TdtmData.CheckID(AID: String): Boolean;
var
  checkID : TJSONObject;
  clientModule : TcmClientModule;
  ok : Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  try
    try
      clientModule := TcmClientModule.Create(Self);
      checkID := clientModule.smMethodsServerClient.CheckID(AID);
      ok := checkID.GetValue<Boolean>('Register', False);
      if not(ok) then
        raise Exception.Create('ID ERROR.');
    finally
      clientModule.DisposeOf;
      checkID.Free; // <-- The error is here (Access violation)
    end;
    Result := ok;
  except
    on e : Exception do
      raise Exception.Create(e.Message);
  end;

end;
```

The smMethodsServerClient.CheckID(AID) method was created automatically through the TDSRestConnection component.

```
function TsmMethodsServerClient.CheckID(AID: string; const ARequestFilter: string): TJSONObject;
begin
  if FCheckIDCommand = nil then
  begin
    FCheckIDCommand  := FConnection.CreateCommand;
    FCheckIDCommand.RequestType := 'GET';
    FCheckIDCommand.Text := 'TsmMethodsServer.CheckID';
    FCheckIDCommand.Prepare(TsmMethodsServer_CheckID);
  end;
  FCheckIDCommand.Parameters[0].Value.SetWideString(AIDPDV);
  FCheckIDCommand.Execute(ARequestFilter);
  Result := TJSONObject(FCheckIDCommand.Parameters[1].Value.GetJSONValue(FInstanceOwner));
end;
```

I also used the Datasnap REST Client Module wizard to create my class TcmClientModule.

Comment: It's a really bad idea to name a variable (`checkID`) the same exact name as the function  (`CheckID`). Delphi is not case sensitive, and old-style Pascal used `functionname := returnvalue` instead of the (now) built-in `Result` to return values from a function.

Comment: The call to `TcmClientModule.Create()` should be above the `try` block. And there should be a second `try..finally` to free the `TJSONObject`, assuming it should be freed to begin with. What does `csmMethodsServerClient.CheckID()` look like?

Comment: If _clientModule := TcmClientModule.Create(Self);_ or _checkID := clientModule.smMethodsServerClient.CheckID(AID);_ fails with an exception, the FINALLY block is executed without _checkID_ being initialized (see Remy's comment above), which would most likely result in an access violation when you try to free an uninitialized object. That's why you should always place the allocation/initialization of a protected object _outside_ the TRY/FINALLY block.

Comment: Is this sort of a DataSnap application?

Comment: It is a datasnpat application.

Comment: In your original code, without doing `checkID.Free`, what are the memory leak details (what are the objects that are not being freed)? Are there any other objects beside TJSONObject that are not being freed?

Comment: @peter.aryanto I'm using madExcept and it shows the following memory leak:
Type: GetMem,
Value: $f510918,
Size: 2,
access: read / writte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSONValue used as a parameter of DataSnap does not need to be Free.

In addition, if you release the memory of the parameter object, an error may occur when you release the DataSnap DataModule or when you call the interface where the parameter was used for the second time.

Even if you create a new JSONValue parameter every time to use the DataSnap interface, there are no problems such as memory leaks.

Moreover, JSONValue objects received as a result of the DataSnap interface should not be freed further.

=================================================

```
clientModule.DisposeOf;
```

This frees memory for checkID. However, there is no setting for "checkID := nil". The conditional statement below will always be executed and an error occurs when executing.

```
if Assigned(checkId) then 
  checkID.Free;
```

Comment: In this case, can I disregard the memory leak shown by MadExcept?

Comment: @DeivisÁtila Yes. You can ignore it. In fact, if you do the stress test yourself, you can see that the memory does not increase.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe when you are doing this thing

```
clientModule.DisposeOf;
```

`checkID` will be destroyed, because `checkID` is a part of `clientModule` due to this part of code

```
clientModule.smMethodsServerClient.CheckID(AID);
```

You can try clear `checkID` first and then clear `clientModule`.

Update: Another way to avoid error is checking `checkId` before destroying.
Maybe this way is suitable:

```
if Assigned(checkId) then 
  checkID.Free;
```

Maybe besides this check you need check object for `null` too.

Comment: I tried to give the free first and an error also occurs.

Comment: @DeivisÁtila I update my answer, maybe this will help you

Comment: The error continues, I am thinking of stop using the wizard and create my own class to make requests. Thank you.

Comment: @DeivisÁtila Not at all. Sadly that you can not solve your problem.